# How do I display the battery status icon in the taskbar?

Tags: indicator

I have recently downloaded ubuntu 13.10 and am a first time user of this OS. How do I display the battery status icon in the taskbar in ubuntu 13.10. I am unable to see the battery percentage status in the taskbar. Request you to help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just enter your Power settings(type power in the dash) and select to always show the battery icon.

You can also select to show the time left:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Try

   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
2. If it's not working install

   sudo apt-get install indicator-power (if not installed)

further

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status && sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install battery-status
```

Comment: That repository has no packages for current supported ubuntu versions.