# putting a battery status icon into my stalone

Tags: 14.04, icons, power-management, indicator, battery

I'm running Trusty-tahr using fvwm, so I don't automatically get access to the battery status icon that's available in the standard ubuntu desktop manager.    I'd like to put the standard icon into my stalone tray, but I can't find a command-line command that will access the icon.   I have the package `indicator-power` downloaded but there is no executable associated with this word.

Thanks for any advice.

Please note that because the information in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423805/how-do-i-display-the-battery-status-icon-in-the-taskbar) thread is all outdated, this question is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: Did you try fdpowermon?  I've seen that in other configs, dunno if you have to swallow it into FvwmButtons or if it runs in the tray...

Comment: thanks very much @stephen for the suggestion.   I installed it and it looked as though it was just what I wanted.     But I couldn't get it to do anything.    When I  typed `fdpowermon &` nothing happened.     The man page *seemed* to suggest that if I wanted the default settings this should work.   I wonder if anybody has any suggestions.

Comment: Apparently it runs in a system tray, so you have to launch something like trayer or stalonetray, too.

Comment: Now it's working great in the stalone tray, thanks very much!    Wondering if it's possible to configure `theme.cfg` so that it will send an aggressive message via `libnotify` when battery level falls below a certain level.   I believe it's possible to do this using perl, thru `theme.pl` but I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: Looks like you can change the function in theme.pl that gets called on suspend to do some other command.  Like invoking notify-send?  So "notify-send 'Low battery' 'You need to plug in!'" maybe?  From the readme it might already do something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fdpowermon package provides a battery status indicator that docks to the system tray.  So:

Via a shell:

```
sudo apt-get install fdpowermon
sudo apt-get install stalonetray
```

Then in your FVWM StartFunction:

```
AddToFunc StartFunction
+ I Test (init) Exex exec stalonetray
+ I Test (init) Exec exec fdpowermon
```

Changes will be there next log in.

Comment: Thanks very much for looking into this.     I've been activating it with a bash script on startup, bcause FVWM is *so* diffficult to deal with, works fine my way though.